# Local Multiplayer using Mirror in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, unity3d-mirror

I've searched a lot of articles about how to make multiplayer using Mirror, but I don't know how to create LAN multiplayer. Can you advise me some useful materials or show example script please?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the Network Address field on NetworkManager is set to the LAN IP of the host, or if using the NetworkManagerHUD that the text box is set to the LAN IP of the host.

A correct setting, for example, is "192.168.8.100", "10.0.0.100", "172.16.42.69"
An incorrect setting, for example, is "localhost" or "203.200.110.100"

Here's [a link](https://mirror-networking.gitbook.io/docs/faq#to-another-instance-on-the-same-network-lan) with more information about it.